# Update Stack Exchange login email and Jobs email?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email, jobs

I have recently changed my email and have updated it on Stack Overflow under:

*Edit Profile & Settings* → *Email Settings* → *Edit Email Settings**

My email shows as having been updated (and yes, I have reverified it); it also states it affects Stack Overflow + 19 other communities.

However I am unsure how to go about updating it elsewhere, such as:

*Edit Profile & Settings* → *Site Settings* → *My Logins*

Under this heading the **Stack Exchange** option shows my *old* email, but it doesn't show an option to change it? **Other** shows my *new* email.

Additionally, when I went to apply for a job, it still auto fills in my old email - how do I change this there too? Maybe I'm blind, but I couldn't figure out how to edit my email for that anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting my old email stackechange login and *then* using the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/192985) from this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers).

Other than that, with regards to job applications, as @David Fullteron pointed, it takes the info from your last application and prefills it, so the next time you change it all future applications will be prefilled correctly with your new information.

Answer (score 5):

Logins work a bit differently than other email addresses, since they're a credential we use to authenticate you. You can't update them, but you can [add your email as a new login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) and then remove the old one.

On Jobs, I believe that we pre-fill the email address from your last application. So the only way to update this is to submit a new application with a new email address.

Comment: I can't seem to see a way to add a new email login for the stackexchange login type; it only has options for adding a new login via: Google, FaceBook, LiveJournal, Blogger, AO or OpenID.