# How can I change my login address?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

Screenshot 1. The new email address was already added.
[image]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4431/36495023506_4326b2aaa2_o.jpg))</sub>
Screenshot 2. The old email address was already removed.
[image]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4438/36542801685_dbf4f47a79_o.jpg))</sub>
Screenshot 3. My email address was already updated.
[image]
Screenshot 4. I cannot use the new address (already added) to log in and still have to use the old one (already removed) to log back in.
[image]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4433/35753416083_b88f9a4a06_o.jpg))</sub>

Please see the above screenshots. My old email address was already removed, but I still have to use it to log into Stack Exchange. I want to use my new address instead of my old address as the login address. How can I do so?

I read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers) and used the 'Send Recovery Email' method, but the email sent to my new address only allowed me to recover account for my old address although it had already been removed.

Comment: You should see "remove" link to the bottom right of each login. Click it for the old login, and it will be removed.

Comment: Sorry, so I'm not sure what's going on. Better wait for a staff member to come over and take a look. In the meanwhile, you can click the "contact" link in the bottom of the page, choose "Other" as type of request, and explain the issue there. This creates an official support request for Stack Exchange team, which might take a while to be processed.

Comment: I have revised my question. Please read again and tell me whether you understand what's going on.

Comment: No, sorry. Personally didn't have to remove any login, so can't really tell how it works from personal experience, just what I know from reading.

Comment: You're saying you still can't log in with your new email after adding it? What happens if you try?

Comment: Heh oh great, we removed the Email field from the main profile edit screen so those instructions you found no longer work. *sigh* This just got a whole lot more complicated when it was already complicated.

Comment: @ Cai, yes I am saying that I still can't log in with my new address after adding it and removing the old one. When I tried using the new one to log in, I got [this message](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4433/35753416083_b88f9a4a06_o.jpg), and I had to use the old one to log back in. You may try for yourself.

Comment: @animuson, you are a moderator, so can you tell me how I can change my login email address? If that cannot be done in the present, can such a feature be added? There is no reason a user cannot change their login address.

Comment: @MatthewWai I've updated the instructions there. The process is mostly the same and should still work if the email has been added to your account as a verified email. If you're still having problems, I recommend the [contact form](/contact).

Comment: @ animuson, I added one more screenshot in my question. It shows that my email address has been updated. However, it still doesn't work. I still have to use the old address to log back in, so I have contacted the Stack Exchange Team as you suggested.

Comment: @MatthewWai That screenshot doesn't really tell me anything. *Only* setting your email there **does not let you login with it**. Please [complete these instructions from step 2 onward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers). Make sure you type the new email into the account recovery screen.

Comment: @ animuson, the 'Send Recovery Email' method works after removing the old email address. My problem has been solved. How can I delete my message already sent to the Stack Exchange Team via the contact form?