# How do I change the e-mail address I log in with?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

First, I am very aware this seems like a duplicate. I have already tried the approach described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/136873) and, as I commented, it failed.

What I have - a Stack Exchange login associated with an old e-mail address which will soon no longer be valid.

What I want - a Stack Exchange login associated with a new e-mail address.

I have already associated this e-mail address with my account in e-mail settings, and as part of following the instructions linked above, have logged in using that e-mail address - but that's still really using the old details - the new password that I set up following the recovery step is still (on the My Logins) associated with the old e-mail address. It looks very much as if when I delete that old Stack Exchange login (with the e-mail address which soon won't be valid) I lose any ability to login because by deleting that I delete the password too.

I'm aware that I can set up as many new logins as I want, but these are logins using third-party accounts that I don't want to use and which I mostly don't even have - I don't have a Facebook account etc etc etc.

The "My Logins" page doesn't appear to allow me to change the e-mail address for my existing login. Nor does it allow me to create a new Stack Exchange login and delete the old one. With the new e-mail address associated with my new account due to following those instructions, I now doubt that I can follow the various clues I've seen about creating independent accounts and getting them merged and, having already spent more than an hour on this (stumbling around my profile in disbelief even before thinking that maybe this really *is* hard enough to need Meta questions and answers) and having followed instructions from a recent Meta answer only to find they're not just unnecessarily obscure, indirect, long-winded and complex, they don't even work, I really want more direct and reliable guidance than whichever breadcrumbs I stumble on next. And with this being the first account I'm trying to change, I seriously hope all the rest won't take this long.

BTW - why is such an obviously needed thing made so stupidly difficult "by design"? I see lots of comments pointing out that an e-mail address blatantly is not a permanent property of a person, I see nothing that gives reasons for the decision. "By design" in itself is **NOT** a reason, and in the many contexts where that's all the justification that's stated, looks like a deliberate evasion.

Also, the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) does not seem to include advice for when people need to change their e-mail address in the "Accounts, registration and logging in" section. Why not?

Comment: Go to your profile to "Edit Profile & Settings", then to "My Logins". If your new login details are there, you are ok. You can remove the login that is going to expire. If it isn't there, you can click "add more logins...".

Comment: @Oded - it's there as "Other" (not "StackExchange") and doesn't have a password associated (no "Change Password" link). Instead, the password intended for the new login was associated with the old one. When I click "add more logins", the options are things like Facebook - there's no option to add a replacement StackExchange login.

Comment: Yes, that's... more involved... See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/140505

Comment: @Oded - Although the final 6 characters of your link are different (140505 rather than 136783) that appears to be the exact same answer to the exact same question that I linked myself at the top of my question - the instructions that I've already tried to follow, which have already failed, and to which I've already added a comment saying the answer failed and how.

Comment: Delete the created openId that you do not want (the one using the new email address) and repeat the process - account recovery should get you there.

Comment: @Oded - I trust you mean the one using the *old* e-mail address. Trusting you, giving it a go, be back (I hope) soon...

Comment: @Oded - OK, that worked. This still seems absurd. I realise there was a comment on that answer suggesting deleting the old login, but seriously, I don't think many people would just delete their last login option with a password attached just to see if it works, and I didn't even see the comment until after trying to follow the answer failed. This whole obscure, indirect, long-winded and complex procedure should IMHO be replaced with something sane, or at the very least should be explained in the FAQ with the rationale (I assume there was some) explained somewhere that's easy to find too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's now a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/136873, but I can't add an extra note with close-as-duplicate. Extra note is that the relevant answer didn't originally solve my issue, but I've added a comment. Would be nice if the answer itself was updated, I'm not confident enough (and maybe don't have enough meta points), but now that my issue is resolved this question is just noise.