# Turn off Facebook login

Tags: support, login, facebook

At one point many years ago, Facebook login made sense to me. There have been enough changes that it doesn't anymore, at least to me.

How do I switch to having a username/password while keeping the rest of my account intact?

I don't think this is a duplicate, though it probably seems so from the title. I'd like to be able to add enough to my account to use the simple username/password prompt. There doesn't seem to be a way to activate that in the current website, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers for how to add a Stack Exchange login- That's what gives you the simple username/password method

Comment: Thank you, @Kendra. I'm still waiting on the email step, but that looks like exactly what I want. I never would have figured that out without that link.

Comment: @Kendra's link was everything I needed. I don't have the reputation on meta to close this as a dupe, but you guys are certainly welcome to. :)

Comment: That post has now been added to the duplicates list.