# Confusion about Change of Email

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I changed my login email exactly [the way it is described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers). Now, I cannot understand why the old email that I **removed** as a login still would work when I type it in:

[image]

I don't understand this.

Why is my old email still saved on SO? It shouldn't show the Figure I pasted. It should show me that the email is not known or sth alike..

Answer (score 5):

When you set up a password for an email address on our network, you are actually creating an [OpenID credential](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) with that email and password. While we discontinued OpenID services years ago, the underlying mechanism for credential creation is still exactly the same. Deleting a credential from your account only disassociates it from your account - it does *not* delete the credential itself. Thus you can still use it to login and create a new profile.

If you'd like to delete the credential itself so the password no longer exists, you'll need to [contact us](/contact) identifying the email that you'd like the credential deleted for. They can only be deleted by staff.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure: (i) The credentials that I use now would not be affected by this, correct? I changed the password as well. (ii) What should I choose concerning "What can we help you with?"

Comment: No, you have a separate credential "account" for each email address you choose to set up. They are deleted individually as well. You can simply choose Other and explain the situation. Support does not pay any attention to the option chosen.