# Migrating Badges and Reputations of Stackoverflow from one account to another upon organization change

Tags: discussion, reputation

Is there way to transfer my Badges and Reputations of Stackoverflow to another account. My current account is tied to email Id provided by my employer. If I quit my current organization then the email will be deactivated and I will have to forgo all my Reputations earned.
Only option is to create a new personal email id and change my current profile settings to point to new personal email id. Is this the only way to transfer?

Comment: You don't need to 'transfer' anything. All you need to do is add this personal e-mail address as a way to login with, on the [my logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) page. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/369802) describes how to do so.

Comment: If you do not want to change your login, then there is sadly no way to do what you want.