# Is there a unified portal/dashboard to update/change user account details and login credentials for all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, login, user-accounts

I have searched across portals and multiple pages Google search results, but I couldn't find any definitive way to update my account details uniformly for all the Stack Exchange sites.

Heck, there  still isn’t any clear cut solution to update the login credentials, till date.

Considering the popularity and versatility of these sites, I feel it’s high time that a unified dashboard/portal is built where the users can at least control/update their basic settings like their profile information, login credentials... which will reflect across all Stack Exchange sites.

Is there a unified portal/dashboard to update/change user account details and login credentials for all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: You can manage your credentials on any site for all sites. And when you change your about me, location, website etc you can click "Save and copy changes to all public communities" which achieves what you ask for. I don't see much value in having to go to a different portal/dashboard first to do what I can do today.

Comment: I agree... but if I want to change my login email id for all the StackExchange site, there's still no clear cut solution for it.

In my opinion, it'll be a far better user experience if the basic functionalities were added to the main StackExchange portal, considering that a page close to this already exists for all users at

stackexchange.com / users /{useridnumber} / {useridname}

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: The main stackexchange portal is scheduled for an overhaul where the outcome might be that it totally disappears, specially for the user related functionality.

Comment: *it'll be a far better user experience if the basic functionalities were added to the main StackExchange portal* No. The general design principle of an SE site is that you should be able to use it without ever knowing it is part of a larger network. Moving user account management to a portal / dashboard would defeat that goal.

Comment: Oh that would be taking a step back from a better approach. Also the above two links have information which are now outdated. I had tried these methods, but I still couldn't login using the newly added email address. Had to go back to logging in with the old email id

Comment: "The general design principle of an SE site is that you should be able to use it without ever knowing it is part of a larger network." Well, isn't it better to let the users know that in the first place, considering the fact that every user at some point or the other will stumble upon https://stackexchange.com/sites, and have some major confusion at the beginning

Comment: If you encounter a bug with accounts I suggest you use the Contact link at the bottom of the page. That might resolve the issue where adding new features might not.

Comment: Yes, will probably do that. @rene Could you please kindly not downvote my question ? My main intention was to highlight this issue, considering a lot of users keep asking about the same thing and come across very ambiguous, outdated solutions.

Comment: I downvote feature requests that I consider not useful. I want the SE team to focus on current problems, not add more problems. Outdated solutions need to be edited. If you have found out what the issue was with your account creation, feel free to suggest an edit so the next person doesn't have to make the same mistake.  Also see: [voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 2):

On any of your site profiles, under ["Your Logins"/"My Logins"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) it says:

> Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

Because many users belong to multiple sites (I'm at 30+), most preferences work across all sites. Only display name, profile picture, and profile text can be customized per site, but they can also easily be kept the same across all sites.