# How to change account login email

Tags: support, login, email

I'm trying to make a change to my Stack Exchange account's login email but it seemed to fail.
I did update the email address from my “profile” and validated the new email address via the confirmation letter.

However, when I use the new email address login to any Stack Exchange website, the webpage always told me error messages: “An error occurred with log in.” and “No user found with matching email”
Therefore I had no choice but to login using my old email address.

I checked a dozen times in the email settings, and it is updated with my new mail address. Weird.

Can anyone give me some hints please?

Comment: The target of several duplicates: [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers)

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to use the [contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form to get support. Use "Account issue" and "I need to add or remove login credentials" for "What can we help you with?" Note, I just tried to add another login to my account but it worked and I was unable to reproduce this. Might be something about your email that doesn't work with SE.

Comment: Moving to leave open since, as the question points out, the user is facing an error message when following the procedure in the linked post.